# How to customise the amount of a Paypal subscription made using JS SDK

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to upgrade a legacy system that uses Paypal for subscriptions.  The older way redirects to Paypal (Checkout?) and the new way is trying to use their JavaScript SDK:

https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/reference/

```
return actions.subscription.create({
      'plan_id': 'P-2UF78835G6983425GLSM44MA'
    });
```

The older system created Payment Plans on the fly, and so the payer was able to adjust the amount rather than sticking with the amount stored in a pre-made plan.  I hope to replicate this behaviour using the JS sdk.

The above pages links to here: https://developer.paypal.com/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create "for allowed options defined in the request body."

One of the parameters within the subscription creation is:
plan [object]
"An inline plan object to customise the subscription. You can override plan level default attributes by providing customised values for the subscription in this object."

This seems like the thing I am after but I am unable to get Papal to use anything I put inside there, ie:

```
plan_id: plan_id,
custom_id: "Does this thing work?",
plan_overridden: true,
plan: {name: "Testing ABC123 Special"}
```

"Does this thing work?" will carry but nothing within the plan.

One other thing of note is that the older system didn't pass a plan_id, which doesn't seem possible with the JS SDK.

I think the older way is using Checkout, are these two methods completely imcompatible?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`name` cannot be overridden.

Keys that *can* be overridden are documented in the [plan_override](https://developer.paypal.com/api/subscriptions/v1/#definition-plan_override) object.

---

If you need to customize more plan details, create the subscription on the server side and return its id to the calling JS (within that server route, the plan_id can first be created on the fly if one doesn't already exist for the name you need)

```html
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;vault=true&amp;intent=subscription&amp;currency=USD"></script>

  <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

  <script>
    paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          label:'subscribe'  //Optional text in button
      },
      createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
          return fetch('/path/on/your/server/paypal/subscription/create/', {
              method: 'post'
          }).then(function(res) {
              return res.json();
          }).then(function(serverData) {
              console.log(serverData);
              return serverData.id;
          });
      },

      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      /*  Optional: At this point, notify your server of the activated subscription...

          fetch('/path/on/your/server/paypal/subscription/activated/' + data.subscriptionID , {
              method: 'post'
          }).then(function(res) {
              return res.json();
          }).then(function(serverData) {
              //
          });
      */
          //You could additionally subscribe to a webhook for the BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED event (just in case), as well as other future subscription events
          //Ref: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions

          // Show a message to the buyer, or redirect to a success page
          alert('You successfully subscribed! ' + data.subscriptionID);
      }

    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  </script>
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  The name cannot be changed, that's what threw me off seemingly!

Answer (score 0):

My answer was found on this page:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/subscriptions/customize/bill/

```
                  billing_cycles: [
                    {
                      sequence: 1,
                      total_cycles: 0,
                      pricing_scheme: {
                        fixed_price: {
                          value: "8",
                          currency_code: "USD",
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
```

It didn't make the name change but it did make the amount change which is actually all I care about :)