# How to add a setup_fee on paypal subscription revise via JS SDK?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I've created two plan for the same product: both have a duration of 1 month, one has a price of 15€ and the second one has a price of 40€.

If a user have buyed the cheaper one, I'd like to let him pay the difference if he tries to buy the expensive one.

[I think this answer is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71974648/how-to-charge-prorated-rate-on-paypal-subscription/71976610#71976610), but can't find the proper way to do it via JS SDK.

Notes: none of the two plan have a setup_fee.

This is the JS code I wrote.

```js
      paypal.Buttons({
        createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
          if(settings.megapro.subscription_id !== void 0){
            // if we have a subscription_id, then let use revise method
            let revise_obj = {
              "plan_id": selector.dataset.plan_id,
            };
            if(selector.dataset.prorata !== void 0){
              revise_obj.plan = {
                payment_preferences: {
                  setup_fee: {
                    currency_code: "EUR",
                    value: selector.dataset.prorata
                  }
                }
              };
            }
            return actions.subscription.revise(settings.megapro.subscription_id, revise_obj);
```

It opens the Paypal windows, asks for credentials, ask to confirm the new subscription price but don't say a word about setup fee.
The user confirm the new subscription, and everything go on normally.
But when I go in the buyer sandbox I can see there's no payment for the setup_fee, and the same also in the seller sandbox account.

**UPDATE**

I've tried to change the billing_cycles in this way:

```js
              let revise_obj = {
                "plan_id": selector.dataset.plan_id,
              };

              revise_obj.plan = {};
              revise_obj.plan.billing_cycles = [
                {
                  sequence: 1,
                  total_cycles: 1,
                  tenure_type: "TRIAL",
                  frequency: {
                    interval_unit: "DAY",
                    interval_count: 1
                  },
                  pricing_scheme: {
                    fixed_price: {
                      value: selector.dataset.prorata,
                      currency_code: "EUR",
                    },
                  },
                },
                {
                  sequence: 2,
                  total_cycles: 0,
                  tenure_type: "REGULAR",
                  frequency: {
                    interval_unit: "MONTH",
                    interval_count: 1
                  },
                  pricing_scheme: {
                    fixed_price: {
                      value: selector.dataset.price,
                      currency_code: "EUR",
                    },
                  },
                }
              ];

            }
            return actions.subscription.revise(settings.megapro.subscription_id, revise_obj);
```

but then I have this error in developer console:

```
Error: Revise Subscription Api HTTP-422 response: error:

{
    "name": "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
    "message": "The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
    "debug_id": "f4150769c579b",
    "details": [
        {
            "field": "/plan/billing_cycles/1/sequence",
            "value": "2",
            "location": "body",
            "issue": "INVALID_BILLING_CYCLE_SEQUENCE",
            "description": "The provided billing cycle sequence is not available."
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
            "rel": "information_link",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
    at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?...
```

How can I try to solve this?

Comment: I've tried also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70786216/1838698), but with no luck...

Answer (score 0):

I think setup_fee only applies to first time subscriptions

For later revision of an existing subscription, you'll have to patch to add a 1 cycle trial period with the one-time fee or prorated amount you want it to charge next month, and then have the new regular billing cycle after that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated the question with the result of your suggestions.

Comment: Try with an API call rather than client side, you may need to "op:add" the second cycle rather than op:replace

Comment: To use the op:replace / op:add I have to use the update method, but with that method I can't change the plan_id. 

I'm trying with the REST API to revise the subscription. 
I will update the question as soon as I have something new.

Comment: You may need to revise with a new plan_id first and then patch the one-off details